# how to change submit button to next?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

Using orchard 1.6 in the forms. I want to change the text in 'Submit' button to 'next' as the user has to complete 5 forms before finishing.

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found is by using jQuery on page load:

```
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Change text of button
        $('.your-button').html('Next');

    });
//]]>
```

You'll need to wrap it in a CDATA tag if you want to put it in the editor, or just the single line if you're in a separate js file.
Hope that helps someone.